Contractor Did Not Follow Code When Drilling Through Floor Joists
A plumbing contractor was coming out to replace some of the old galvanized pipes in our home, and asked if I wanted to run the new pipes through the joists (the galvanized pipes were under the joists). I said OK, and then I come to find the holes were not drilled to code.
How bad is this mistake? Should I be concerned about the joists cracking or anything, or is the 2" in the code mainly main to make sure that somebody doesn't accidentally put a drywall screw into the water lines or electrical?


How serious is this?  if the joists are 2 inches oversize it's not serious but otherwise....
Your plumber should contact a structural engineer for an appropriate remedy.

The joists are about 1 inch oversize, when I measured they are 9 inch joists, spanning about 12 feet.

I expect that an engineer will probably tell you this is ok  as is, but you need to ask the engineer not some internet bozo.,

You may need to have the plumber install something like these https://joistrepair.com/products/2x8-dnr-deep-notch-floor-joist-notch-repair-kit https://metwood.com/product/joist-repair-hole-reinforcer-2810hr/ on his dime (or maybe have someone else install them and have the plumber pay for it).
